# I'm trying to run an ansible playbook throws "Found existing installation: requests 2.25.1\n\n:stderr:ERROR: Cannot uninstall requests 2.25.1"

Tags: python, docker, automation, ansible, configuration

I'm trying to run an ansible playbook that installs docker and docker-compose and runs a compose file on a ec2 t2.micro, to use the docker modules in ansible i need to have docker and docker-compose python modules installed in the ec2.

here is my playbook:

```yaml
#play1
- name: Update yum repo, install docker, pip, docker-compose & pip and python modules
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: update yum repo and cache
      yum: 
        name: '*'
        state: latest
        update_cache: true 
    - name: install docker and pip
      yum: 
        name:
          - docker
          - pip
    - name: download and install docker-compose 
      get_url:
        url: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/latest/download/docker-compose-Linux-{{lookup('pipe','uname -m')}}
        dest: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
        mode: +x
    - name: start docker daemon
      systemd:  
        name: docker
        state: started
  ########################################################### this is the trouble part      
    - name: Install docker and docker-compose python module
      pip:
        name: 
          - docker
          - docker-compose
  ############################################################  
#play2
- name: Reset connection #and test hello-world
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:    
    - name:  add ec2-user to docker group
      user: 
        name: ec2-user
        groups: docker
        append: yes    
    - name: reconnect to server session
      meta: reset_connection  
#play3
- name: start docker containers
  hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - docker-vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: copy docker-compose file
      copy: # copy files from controller to remote node
        src: /home/ansible-project/docker-compose.yaml
        dest: /home/ec2-user/docker-compose.yaml
    - name: login to docker private repo
      docker_login:
        registry_url: https://index.docker.io/v1
        username: "{{user_name}}" 
        password: "{{docker_passwd}}"  
    - name: execute docker-compose and start contaier
      docker_compose: 
        project_src: /home/ec2-user
        state: present # equivalent of docker-compose up
```

my host file is simple with a single group and 1 server-ip configured with ansible_user and ssh private key for the login.
the docker-vars.yaml has only my docker username and passwd...

I need to run this completely in single click,

I have tried to run the playbook by installing python3 specifically and select the "interpreter_python= /usr/bin/python3" in the ansible.cfg file and also using the default python installed i,e usr/bin/python3.9, but the playbook runs into an error saying "Found existing installation: requests 2.25.1\n\n:stderr: ERROR: Cannot uninstall requests 2.25.1 Hint: The package was installed by rpm." -- posting only the error part.
.
.
but if i manually log in to the ec2 and do
$ pip install docker
$ pip install docker-compose
the modules are successfully installed.

Comment: If you're just trying to install Docker in an automation scenario, this doesn't quite seem like a programming-related question, and another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be a better place to ask.  You may also want to review the advice in [ask]: this question could be clearer if the YAML file was cut down to the minimum needed to demonstrate the issue and if details like error messages were formatted properly.

Comment: thanks @DavidMaze for the suggestion, posting it in a better way on Devops.